# Agda: run function for Conor's stack example

Tags: agda

At ICFP 2012, Conor McBride gave a keynote with the tile "Agda-curious?".

It featured a small stack machine implementation.

The video is on youtube:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XGyJ519RY6Y

The code is online too:
http://personal.cis.strath.ac.uk/conor.mcbride/ICFP12Code.tgz

I am wondering about the `run` function of Part 5 (i.e. "Part5Done.agda" if you downloaded the code). The talk stops before the `run` function is explained.

```
data Inst : Rel Sg SC Stk where
  PUSH  : {t : Ty} (v : El t) -> forall {ts vs} ->
            Inst (ts & vs) ((t , ts) & (E v , vs))
  ADD   : {x y : Nat}{ts : SC}{vs : Stk ts} ->
            Inst ((nat , nat , ts) & (E y , E x , vs))
              ((nat , ts) & (E (x + y) , vs))
  IFPOP : forall {ts vs ts' vst vsf b} ->
          List Inst (ts & vs) (ts' & vst)  -> List Inst (ts & vs) (ts' & vsf)
          -> Inst ((bool  , ts) & (E b , vs)) (ts' & if b then vst else vsf)

postulate
  Level : Set
  zl : Level
  sl : Level -> Level

{-# BUILTIN LEVEL Level #-}
{-# BUILTIN LEVELZERO zl #-}
{-# BUILTIN LEVELSUC sl #-}

data _==_ {l : Level}{X : Set l}(x : X) : X -> Set l where
  refl : x == x

{-# BUILTIN EQUALITY _==_ #-}
{-# BUILTIN REFL refl #-}


fact : forall {T S} -> (b : Bool)(t f : El T)(s : Stk S) ->
         (E (if b then t else f) , s) ==
         (if b then (E t , s) else (E f , s))
fact tt t f s = refl
fact ff t f s = refl

compile : {t : Ty} -> (e : Expr t) -> forall {ts vs} ->
   List Inst (ts & vs) ((t , ts) & (E (eval e) , vs))
compile (val y)     = PUSH y , []
compile (e1 +' e2)  = compile e1 ++ compile e2 ++ ADD , []
compile (if' e0 then e1 else e2) {vs = vs}
  rewrite fact (eval e0) (eval e1) (eval e2) vs
  = compile e0 ++ IFPOP (compile e1) (compile e2) , []

{- 
-- ** old run function from Part4Done.agda
run : forall {ts ts'} -> List Inst ts ts' -> List Elt ts [] -> List Elt ts' []
run []              vs              = vs
run (PUSH v  , is)  vs              = run is (E v , vs)
run (ADD     , is)  (E v2 , E v1 , vs)  = run is (E 0 , vs)
run (IFPOP is1 is2 , is) (E tt , vs) = run is (run is2 vs)
run (IFPOP is1 is2 , is) (E ff , vs) = run is (run is1 vs)
-}

run : forall {i j} -> List Inst i j -> Sg Stack (λ s -> s == i) → (Sg SC Stk)
run {vs & vstack} [] _
   = (vs & vstack)
run _ _ = {!!} -- I have no clue about the other cases...

--Perhaps the correct type is:
run' : forall {i j} -> List Inst i j -> Sg Stack (λ s -> s == i) → Sg (Sg SC Stk) (λ s → s == j)
run' _ _ = {!!}
```

What is the correct type signature of the `run` function? How should the `run` function be implemented?

The compile function is explained [about 55 minutes into the talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XGyJ519RY6Y#t=55m40) .

The full code is [available from Conor's webpage](http://personal.cis.strath.ac.uk/conor.mcbride/ICFP12Code.tgz).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Guilty as charged, the type of the `run` function from `Part4Done.agda` is

```
run : forall {ts ts'} -> List Inst ts ts' -> List Elt ts [] -> List Elt ts' []
run []              vs              = vs
run (PUSH v  , is)  vs              = run is (E v , vs)
run (ADD     , is)  (E v2 , E v1 , vs)  = run is (E 0 , vs)
run (IFPOP is1 is2 , is) (E tt , vs) = run is (run is2 vs)
run (IFPOP is1 is2 , is) (E ff , vs) = run is (run is1 vs)
```

which amounts to saying "Given code which starts from stack configuration `ts` and finishes in stack configuration `ts'` and a stack in configuration `ts`, you will get a stack in configuration `ts'`. A "stack configuration" is a list of the types of the things pushed on the stack.

In `Part5Done.agda`, the code is indexed not only by the types of what the stack holds initially and finally but also by the values. The `run` function is thus woven into the definition of the code. The compiler is then typed to require that the code produced must have a `run` behaviour which corresponds to `eval`. That is, the run-time behaviour of compiled code is bound to respect the reference semantics. If you want to run that code, to see with your own eyes what you know to be true, type the same function along the same lines, except that we need to select the types alone from the types-and-values pairs which index the code.

```
run : forall {ts ts' vs vs'} -> List Inst (ts & vs) (ts' & vs') -> 
        List Elt ts [] -> List Elt ts' []
run []              vs              = vs
run (PUSH v  , is)  vs              = run is (E v , vs)
run (ADD     , is)  (E v2 , E v1 , vs)  = run is (E (v1 + v2) , vs)
run (IFPOP is1 is2 , is) (E tt , vs) = run is (run is1 vs)
run (IFPOP is1 is2 , is) (E ff , vs) = run is (run is2 vs)
```

Alternatively, you can apply the obvious erasure function which maps the types-and-values-indexed code to types-indexed code, then use the old `run` function. My work with Pierre-Évariste Dagand on *ornaments* automates these patterns of layering an extra index induced by a program systematically over a type then rubbing it out later. It's a generic theorem that if you erase the computed index then recompute it from the erased version, you get (GASP!) exactly the index you erased. In this case, that means `run`ning the code which is typed to agree with `eval` will actually give you the same answer as `eval`.

Comment: You mentioned recomputing the erased information. I guess the `run` function does this. Would the `run` function be generated too with ornaments? If not, how can the "generic theorem" be applied? (I would like to be sure that the `run` function is correct too.)

Comment: In the talk it is also mentioned that the stack example can be extended with jump instructions (perhaps a simple `jump` instruction to implement subroutines or perhaps also `jumpNotZero` loops). Is there a solution that is as straight forward as the other parts (part1-5) of the stack example? I think the `run` function wouldn’t be a total function any more; so something like the Partiality Monad presented at ICFP12 by Nils Danielsson is needed? Is there a more elegant solution?

Comment: @pigworker Forgive me, but with the type you give here I still seem to be able to write the _incorrect_ `run` function that you cited in the talk as the reason for going to such lengths. The type doesn't express the fact that `vs`/`vs'` is the runtime value of the input/output stacks. Would a stronger specification be something like `run : forall {ts ts' vs vs'} -> List Inst (ts & vs) (ts' & vs') -> Sg _ (_==_ vs) -> Sg _ (_==_ vs')` ? (... although it seems strange to be explicitly passing around values provably equal to values already inferred by the type checker. Is there a better way?)

Comment: It's so long ago, I've forgotten. You can certainly give the run function a type which says "if you feed in exactly those values, you'll get out exactly these values". The tricky part is indeed ensuring that you don't just return the values mentioned for specification purposes. Agda, sadly, has no quantifier like Haskell's forall, which guarantees inaccessibility of data at run time. Likewise, Haskell does not yet have Pi. We shall rectify both of these situations, in time.